# issues replacing html with link JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I'm trying to make a text into a link in my Javascript code. This should work but it doesn't.

```
    var strLink = <a href="xxx" style= "text-decoration:none; color:#fff;">"mysite.com" </a>; 
        var cb_header = chatbox.find('.imjs-header');
        cb_header.html(cb_header.html().replace('{username}', strLink));
```

I have a variable called username and it is a string. That is the string that used to replace {username}. Maybe I can use jquery? I can't seem to get it a link though. Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Arjun

Comment: your syntax is wrong; a string variable (_strLink_) needs to be enclosed in quote (") chars. also you'll have to escape actual quotes inside the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var strLink = '<a href="xxx" style= "text-decoration:none; color:#fff;">"mysite.com" </a>'`;

Comment: You'll need a closing ' after </a>. Also Arjun, you won't need quotes around mysite.com unless you want them to actually show up on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var strLink = '<a href="xxx" style= "text-decoration:none; color:#fff;">"mysite.com" </a>';
```